# Graphic problems on Nokia Booklet 3G

Tags: 12.04, graphics, nokia

after installation (no problems) of the latest Ubuntu version (12.04 LTS) on my "Nokia Booklet 3G", I got problems with the monitor.
When I started my Nokia, I got a black sceen and after a while I have a kind of splitted screen... in the upper half of the monitor I can see the half of my wallpaper of the desktop and the lower half of the screen shows me grey color... sometimes the monitor flickers.

I think, there is a problem with the graphics driver.
I already searched in different forums worldwide, but didn't found a useful answer for that problem.

Well, Ubuntu professionals... do you have the final answer ?
I have to say, that I am a Linux beginner and I would really appreciate a practical solution.

Thank you very much in advance.
Kazu

Comment: Your computer has an 'Intel GMA500' graphics card, which seems to have a history of problems. Try working your way through these suggestions:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo#Ubuntu_12.04

Comment: @ David: Thanks for the hint, but I already tried these suggestions --> still problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Ubuntu 12.10 instead. In the latest version this graphics problem is fixed. But I recommend you Lubuntu 12.10. It takes the least amount of memory of all Ubuntu-based distros.

Answer (score 0):

I stronlgy suggest installing LXLE 12.04.5. that has even lower profile and performs best beating Ubuntu and Lubuntu.